# DRY Sass codes that only value changes

Tags: sass

Using sass with rails. In the design, there is a pattern that the space shrink to half from desktop to mobile. Now it ends up like:

```
.my-page {
  .class-a {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .class-b {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px; 
  }
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .my-page {
    .class-a {
      margin-top: 40px;
      margin-bottom: 40px;
    }
    .class-b {
      padding-top: 60px;
      padding-bottom: 60px; 
    }
  }
}
```

Wondering is there a good way to DRY these? Don't wanna repeat writing same classes twice.

Answer (score 2):

A nice way to DRY up your sass is using mixins.

```
@mixin page-spaces($margin, $padding) {
  .my-page {
    .class-a {
      margin-top: $margin;
      margin-bottom: $margin;
    }
    .class-b {
      padding-top: $padding;
      padding-bottom: $padding; 
    }
  }
}

@include page-spaces(20px, 30px);

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  @include page-spaces(40px, 60px);
}
```

[SASS Reference on Mixins](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixins)

**Edit:** In order to clarify the intended use of mixins, here's an extended version with multiple arguments (even a default):

```
@mixin awesome-page-stuff($stylish-margin, $cute-padding, $some-left-margin, $ugly-background: red) {
  .my-page {
    background: $ugly-background;
    .class-a {
      margin-top: $stylish-margin;
      margin-bottom: $stylish-margin;
    }
    .class-b {
      padding-top: $cute-padding;
      padding-bottom: $cute-padding; 
      margin-left: $some-left-margin;
    }
  }
}

@include awesome-page-stuff(20px, 30px, 50px);

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  @include awesome-page-stuff(40px, 60px, 200px, green);
}
```

Comment: Mixin is definitely a way to go. However, page-spaces won't take fixed number of arguments actually since there will be many margins and paddings

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you... ```page-spaces``` (it's an arbitrary name, really, call it whatever you like) can be defined using any number of arguments. Your question is about repeating the same pattern with variable arguments, right?

Answer (score 0):

you can create variables, something like this:

```
$primary-margin: 20px;
$primary-padding: 30px;
.my-page {
  .class-a {
    margin-top: $primary-margin;
    margin-bottom: $primary-margin;
  }
  .class-b {
     padding-top: $primary-padding;
     padding-bottom: $primary-padding; 
  }
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .my-page {
    .class-a {
      margin-top: $primary-margin*2;
      margin-bottom: $primary-margin*2;
    }
    .class-b {
      padding-top: $primary-padding*2;
      padding-bottom: $primary-padding*2; 
    }
  }
}
```